# Is auto director configurable?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Auto director is a usefull feature in demo player which intends to catch frags as much as possible. I want to know if we can configure this. I mean I want to adjust:

1. Delay time (it has a delay time which helps to progress the game
       before we see)
2. Changing camera time (to choose how many sec. before an action
   starts)
3. An option to make it show only mvp'ed players at that round (it may
       need to progress rounds one by one or whole game)
4. priority of players in an action. ( e.g. there are 2 actions in same
   time. First one kills other player with an AR and second one kills
   another player with an awp. I want to make it prefer awp kills in
   this situations)
5. Slow motioning while a player kills

   It may sound too imaginary but idk :)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no way to configure it, as it is set to automatically just go and find well, frags as you said. Maybe in the future they will add a way to configure it to our own specifications, but at the moment, I don't think they're worrying about it all that much.